# ASP .NET MVC Application crashes randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

I have a web site developed in ASP .NET MVC 5. It was working normally during last 9 month but since the web site got many active users (about 200 concurrent) it started to crash randomly in every 25~90 min. The strange part is that there is no exception in my log and the only exception that I could find is this in my event log:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time
>   stamp: 0x5215df96 Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d5305 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0000000000055a0b Faulting process id: 0x2340 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d0e9f87a1fba57 Faulting application path:
>   c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id:
>   97868357-55f2-11e5-80b8-a0d3c1fba76b Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Can any body explain me why it's happening and I can get more detail about exception and it's possible resolutions?

**Update 1:**
I found two hot fixes (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2679415 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2640103 in Microsoft site which seems that is the case. One of them is not applicable for Windows 2012 :| the other one is not accessible to public. My emails to Microsoft site is also not answered!

**Update 2:**
Finally after hours and hours of research and code review I found cause of problem. In my code I was loading a DbSet from my Entity Framework db context. The records of database in that table was huge and because of this my app was crashing. And because I also had app pre initialization configured in IIS after crash again it started to load that DbSet again and here was a loop of crashing and crashing!

Comment: w3wp is an Internet Information Services (IIS) worker process. It's a windows process (w3wp.exe) which runs Web applications, and is responsible for handling requests sent to a Web Server for a specific application pool.

Comment: It may be your application pool size is getting bigger and bigger as the no of users getting increased. Try to recycle the application pool in a specific interval

Comment: @M_Griffiths yes, it causes my application pool to restart and I 'm trying to find out why. What I have found upto now is that an unhandled excpetion is occurs in my application which is strange because I have Elmah logging system installed which should detect every exception from my app. So I think its an exception out of my application scope.

Comment: I think ntdll.dll  is related to [nVidia](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2152651/ntdll-dll-error-diagnosis.html). you can try using profiler or ELMAH for  getting more detail error that will help you find the cause.

Comment: Most probably you are managing several websites with one `ApplicationPool` in this case restarting one website causes restart your website.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi No, I have dedicated application pool for each web site on IIS :|

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 No, I already have Elmah installed, most likely the exception is out of my application.

Comment: @tarzanbappa yes, it's growing for sure, but I doesn't reach the maximum I have set.

Comment: How do you have Elmah set up to capture logs? are you storing them somewhere or in memory? because if you are storing the logs in memory you will lose them every time the app pool recycles...

Comment: @JamieRees Yes, I 'm putting them in file not in memory.

Comment: And your implementation of Elmah works (In normal cases) ?

Comment: @JamieRees yes, it is

Comment: How were you able to find where this was happening? I have same exact issue and probably same scenario with my refactoring.